# terraform asks me for a container name when i terraform init

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

when ever i terraform init, i get this

```
Initializing the backend...
container_name
  The container name.

  Enter a value:
```

I have tried creating a new cluster following Microsoft guide here **https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/learn/quick-kubernetes-deploy-terraform?tabs=azure-cli** and it also didnt work. here is the error below

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/random versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/time versions matching "0.9.1"...
- Finding azure/azapi versions matching "~> 1.5"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/azurerm: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/random: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/time: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵

╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider azure/azapi: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: failed to request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: Those two things are not related. The first one you mention is because there is an input variable which expects a value to be assigned to it. The second one could be a firewall issue.

Comment: @MarkoE thank you for your reply. but whenever i put some random name for the container name in the first one, it gives this error 
```
Initializing the backend...
container_name
  The container name.

  Enter a value: containerx

╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: containers.Client#ListBlobs: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ContainerNotFound" Message="The specified container does not exist.\nRequestId:645930f3-901e-0015-42e2-db26ba000000\nTime:2023-08-31T08:06:27.0826609Z"
│
```

Comment: The module actually doesn't have a variable with that name, so it seems you didn't copy it verbatim.

Comment: @MarkoE so what do you advice i do for the first situation?

Comment: I don't have an advice, since there is no code in the question and you haven't provided what you are using, then I cannot tell what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me, the solution was to leave my company network and use my home wifi.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to provision Kubernetes deployment by following the backend file configuration I was able to provision the resource using Terraform.

The errors you're facing suggest that Terraform is unable to establish a connection with the provider registry (registry.terraform.io). This issue might be arising because you attempted to store the backend configuration file after logging into Azure (`Az`) using a `Service Principal`, yet the problem persists.

To address this problem, you must furnish the `client_id`, `client_secret`, `subscription_id`, and `tenant_id` associated with the service principal within the `backend` section of your Terraform configuration. This step is crucial for resolving the issue and enabling proper communication between Terraform and the Azure provider registry.

**My terraform configuration:**

**Provider.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">=1.0"
  

  required_providers {
    azapi = {
      source  = "azure/azapi"
      version = "~>1.5"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
    random = {
      source  = "hashicorp/random"
      version = "~>3.0"
    }
    time = {
      source  = "hashicorp/time"
      version = "0.9.1"
    }
  }

    backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "v-bolliv"
    storage_account_name  = "demovksb"
    container_name        = "demovksb"
    key                   = "C:/Users/v-bolliv/Desktop/project/August/31-08-2023/New folder/terraform.tfstate"
    subscription_id = ""
    client_id       = ""
    tenant_id       = ""
    client_secret   = ""
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
```

**ssh.tf**

```
resource "random_pet" "ssh_key_name" {
  prefix    = "ssh"
  separator = ""
}

resource "azapi_resource_action" "ssh_public_key_gen" {
  type        = "Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys@2022-11-01"
  resource_id = azapi_resource.ssh_public_key.id
  action      = "generateKeyPair"
  method      = "POST"

  response_export_values = ["publicKey", "privateKey"]
}

resource "azapi_resource" "ssh_public_key" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Compute/sshPublicKeys@2022-11-01"
  name      = random_pet.ssh_key_name.id
  location  = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
}

output "key_data" {
  value = jsondecode(azapi_resource_action.ssh_public_key_gen.output).publicKey
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "random_pet" "rg_name" {
  prefix = var.resource_group_name_prefix
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  location = var.resource_group_location
  name     = random_pet.rg_name.id
}

resource "random_pet" "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_name" {
  prefix = "cluster"
}

resource "random_pet" "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_dns_prefix" {
  prefix = "dns"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "k8s" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name                = random_pet.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_name.id
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = random_pet.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_dns_prefix.id

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "agentpool"
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2_v2"
    node_count = var.node_count
  }
  linux_profile {
    admin_username = var.username

    ssh_key {
      key_data = jsondecode(azapi_resource_action.ssh_public_key_gen.output).publicKey
    }
  }
  network_profile {
    network_plugin    = "kubenet"
    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
  }
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_location" {
  type        = string
  default     = "eastus"
  description = "Location of the resource group."
}

variable "resource_group_name_prefix" {
  type        = string
  default     = "rg"
  description = "Prefix of the resource group name that's combined with a random ID so name is unique in your Azure subscription."
}

variable "node_count" {
  type        = number
  description = "The initial quantity of nodes for the node pool."
  default     = 3
}

variable "msi_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The Managed Service Identity ID. Set this value if you're running this example using Managed Identity as the authentication method."
  default     = null
}

variable "username" {
  type        = string
  description = "The admin username for the new cluster."
  default     = "azureadmin"
}
```

**output.tf**

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

output "kubernetes_cluster_name" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.name
}

output "client_certificate" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config[0].client_certificate
  sensitive = true
}

output "client_key" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config[0].client_key
  sensitive = true
}

output "cluster_ca_certificate" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config[0].cluster_ca_certificate
  sensitive = true
}

output "cluster_password" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config[0].password
  sensitive = true
}

output "cluster_username" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config[0].username
  sensitive = true
}

output "host" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config[0].host
  sensitive = true
}

output "kube_config" {
  value     = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.k8s.kube_config_raw
  sensitive = true
}
```

**Output:**

Commad `Terraform init`

[image]

[image]

Command `Terraform apply`

[image]

[image]